# How to iterate through a TextBlob WordList and find the most common nouns?

Tags: python, nlp, tweepy, textblob, word-list

I'm scraping tweets from Twitter and I'd like to gather a list of all of the nouns from all of the tweets I'm scraping so I can figure out which nouns occur the most frequently.

```
def sentiment_script():


        for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=hashtag_phrase + ' -filter:retweets', lang="en", tweet_mode='extended').items(7):

                text = tweet.full_text

                text = ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", text).split())


                blob = TextBlob(text)

                nouns = (blob.noun_phrases)

                print(nouns)
```

The output is this:

```
['covid', 'richmitch']
['uk', 'england', 'uk', 'johnson', 's approach']
['peoria']
['pa', 'surely', 'secretly trying', 'infect', 'covid', 'never wonkette']
['don t', 'full lockdown', 'cancer etc don t', 'full recovery', 'death rate', 'aren t', 'full lockdown']
['datascience team', 'weekly report', 'new data', 'covid', 'may', 'report sheds light', 'business impacts', 'covid', 'read', 'capraplus']
['osdbu', 'small businesses', 'linked', 'covid']
```

I'm not sure where to proceed next, as when I do this:

```
print(type(nouns))
```

the result is

```
<class 'textblob.blob.WordList'>
<class 'textblob.blob.WordList'>
<class 'textblob.blob.WordList'>
<class 'textblob.blob.WordList'>
<class 'textblob.blob.WordList'>
<class 'textblob.blob.WordList'>
<class 'textblob.blob.WordList'>
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

print(type.text) ?